# I want to show the array value one by one (0 to i ) in a text view

Tags: android, arrays, loops, android-studio, textview

I'm a beginner in android development and I want to build a small App that give you the possibility to show the values of an array into the `text view` but I want it to show one and then diapers that the second value then diapers .... that will happen after the `onClick` method :
This is my Java Code :

```
  public void GetMyIdea(View view)  {
    String testatrix[]={"a","s","d", "f","g"};
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    for(int l=0; l<1; l++){
        tv.append(testatrix[l]);
    }


}
```

this code to me the all values of the array at ones ... I want to show one than the next one then the next one .....

I want to the execution of this code be like that :

1- you enter on the app.
2- you click on the button.
3- than you see in the screen the fist value "a".
4- then you press the button again. 
5- the first value "a" will be clean and you see the second value "b". 
.
.
. again and again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.oncreate {GetMyIdea(null);}
2. btn click call GetMyIdea(view);

```
    int index=0;
    public void GetMyIdea(View view)  {
        String testatrix[]={"a","s","d", "f","g"};
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


            tv.setText(testatrix[index]);
            if(index>=testatrix.length){
              index=0; 
           }
           else{
            index+=1;

             }
    }
```

Comment: There just a small problem ... if you arrived in the final value and all the value are been in the screen you see the error message : unfortunately your app has been stooped ... you have a solution to this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this below. Now whenever you click the button the text has been displayed as per the index of your array

```
 int i = 0;
 public void GetMyIdea(View view)  {
    String testatrix[]={"a","s","d", "f","g"};
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


     tv.setText(testatrix[i]);

     i+=1;  //Incrementing the value by l

        if(i >= testatrix.length){
           i = 0;
     } 
 }
```